# JavaScript Canvas - window resize redraw

Tags: javascript, canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/27WVW/1/

### I have a canvas element that uses SetInterval to animate the entrance of a background.

```
var c=document.getElementById("theCircle")

function drawCircle(end=2*Math.PI){

height = window.innerHeight
width = window.innerWidth

var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(width/2,height/2,radius,0,end,true);
ctx.lineWidth=end/5;
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

}


function counter(start,finish,speed){

var i = start

var animation = setInterval(function(){
    i += speed
    if(i>=finish){clearInterval(animation)}
    drawCircle(i);  
    }, 20)
}

counter(0.0,2*Math.PI,0.05)
```

### **On window resize the canvas element is resized to fit the window so that it always fills the page.**

```
window.addEventListener('resize',posFix,false);

function posFix(){

c.height = window.innerHeight
c.width = window.innerWidth

drawCircle();

}
```

When the canvas element is resized the drawing inside is deleted. As you can see, I am calling a redraw on resize but it doesn't seem to fire properly.

What am I missing?

Comment: `drawCircle(end=2*Math.PI)` is a syntax error. What browser are you using that doesn't complain about this?

Comment: @p.s.w.g I'm using firefox

Comment: Okay, well if you want your site to be usable by anyone not using the latest version of FF, I'd recommend using more traditional methods of specifying default values. See the browser compatibility chart [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/default_parameters)

Comment: @p.s.w.g isn't drawCircle(end=2*Math.PI) the same as drawCircle(end=6.283185307179586), which is valid?

Comment: @AllTheTime Default values for arguments are a recent addition (in ES6), and aren't supported in older browsers. [More info](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-default-argument.html)

Comment: @p.s.w.g Honestly, this issue seems tangential to my concerns. Even if I don't use default values I still have the issue where the canvas won't redraw on resize.

Comment: @AllTheTime Agreed, this is not your primary issue. The comment was intended to be general advice, not an answer to your question.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Well, thanks for your insight :)

Comment: Um - I'd say as your interval reached the end, and has been cleared calling drawCircle will put the drawn line outside the viewport. Is this what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/27WVW/3/ (redrawing the entire animation after resize)

Comment: @eithedog oh, that's a good point. I guess the drawing I want depends on being iterated by setInterval. The only problem with your solution is that when the window is resized many "resize" events are fired which leads the the shape being drawn multiple times which gives weird, choppy, bold lines. I just need to find a way to have it only fire once I guess.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/27WVW/4/ ? (I've moved initialization of the animation interval outside the function `counter`, so that it has global scope - this way you can clear the animation inside the `posFix`; i've also commented out the initial call of counter as the resize event is called on the document load)

Comment: @eithedog Yeah that looks great. I'll accept it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed within the comments, the solution is to clear the animation interval within the resize event and then restart the animation.

```
var c = document.getElementById("theCircle"),
    radius = 800;

posFix();

window.addEventListener('resize', posFix, false);

function posFix() {

    c.height = window.innerHeight
    c.width = window.innerWidth

    clearInterval(animation);
    counter(0.0, 2 * Math.PI, 0.05)

}


function drawCircle(end = 2 * Math.PI) {

    height = window.innerHeight
    width = window.innerWidth

    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(width / 2, height / 2, radius, 0, end, true);
    ctx.lineWidth = end / 5;
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

var animation;

function counter(start, finish, speed) {

    var i = start
    animation = setInterval(function () {

        i += speed

        if (i >= finish) {
            clearInterval(animation);
        }

        drawCircle(i);

    }, 20);
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/27WVW/4/